# How to resize an html body background?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I am programming with VB and need to resize the background of a body section for an email. I am fairly new to using VB and html code have tried many examples from online, but everything seems to be formatted using 'colons' rather than 'equals' signs. The html that I was given is as follows:

```
<BODY id=emailBody background='cid:Image'>
```

In Context:

```
Dim htmlBody As String = "<BODY id=emailBody background='cid:Image'>"
```

The code is currently used by VB to insert a background image into an email, but the image is too small and gets tiled whereas I would like to stretch it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Background image support is quite limited and should be avoided as part of an email design.

See: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: The code needs to work for IE8, that might be another problem. Is there another tag that I could use instead of body to layer images such that an image would appear to be a background?

Comment: Yeah, IE8 is a show-stopper for this. Regardless of the browser used, a lot of mail clients do not allow CSS backgrounds. Absolute-positioning would be the alternative, and this too is not allowed by most mail clients. You need to design for the capabilities of the audience, so backgrounds are out, period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the backround-size CSS property to 100% to stretch the background image as explained in this article: http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspbgsize.htm

```
Dim htmlBody As String = "<BODY id=emailBody background='cid:Image' style='background-size:100%;'>"
```

Try these two additional approaches:
1) background-size:auto;
`Dim htmlBody As String = "<BODY id=emailBody background='cid:Image' style='background-size:auto;'>"` as shown at http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

2) If the email client does not respect background-size:auto;, than create a table element with Width and Height set in 100% and applied background image to the table. Here is the markup:

```
<table width="100%" height="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" style="background-image: url('background_image.png');">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p>Content on a pretty background image.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I think I tried this a few times today. Trying again, I'm afraid there is no change to the background when I try this whether I use '10%' or '100%'. I also tried replacing with '500' and '500px'.